# How to change default behavior of enter key?

Tags: php, jquery

It's a chat application code in notepad++. My enter key is not working as it gives a new line always. I tried to find the problem but couldn't rectify it,
It will be of great help if someone can spot and rectify the problem?

```
 ?
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="../Style/Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..Js/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Chat Application Home</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#ChatText").keyup(function(e){
                //When We Press Enter Do
                if(e.keyCode ==13){
                    var ChatText = $("#ChatText").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'InsertMessage.php',
                        data:{ChatText:ChatText},
                        success:function(){

                            $("#ChatText").val("");
                        }

                    });
                }
            });


    });

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Welcome <span style="color:green"><?php echo $_SESSION['UserName'];?></span></h2>
    </br></br>

    <div id="ChatBig">

    <div id="ChatMesseges">

    </div>

    <textarea id="ChatText" name="ChatText"></textarea>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you didn't suppress the enter key's normal behavior... you intercept it, but then allow it to go on as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent the default behaviour on key press. Use [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) or `return` to do that, then run your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel the default behaviour of the `enter` `keypress` event. Add this to your code:

```
$("#ChatText").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode ==13){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that this is a different event; leave the `keyup` handling as-is, or alternatively, change your code to respond to the `keypress` event instead of the `keyup` event, and add the `return false;` there. Both ways are fine.